# Java, compare keyboard input values with file.txt values

Tags: java, file, dictionary, hashmap

SOLVED!

I have a kind of homework, where I have a file where I have username and password like this:

user1       password1

user2       password2

user3       password3

I need to use FileInputStream class, and I also need to keyboard input username and password and check if it already exists (every username must match password, on line). I decided to use Map for that but .... if you take a look into my while loop, I tried to split into key and value. I also created map2 who stores keyboard input, and map who stores split key and value.

My trouble is here: if I input username: user1, password: password1, that condition if(map.equals(map2)) will return true. But if I write for username: user2 and password: password2, "if" will return false, even if user2 and password2 already exists in my file.

Tip: I can't override equals() and hashCode() because I don't have any class here, out of my main class.

```
public class ex_2 
{
public static void main(String args[]) throws IOException
{
    InputStreamReader reader = new InputStreamReader(System.in);
    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(reader);
    System.out.print("username: ");
    String user = br.readLine();
    System.out.print("password : ");
    String pass = br.readLine();

    FileInputStream input= new FileInputStream("file.txt");
    BufferedReader read= new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(input));


    Map<String, String> map = new HashMap<String,String>();
    Map<String, String> map2 = new HashMap<String,String>();
    map2.put(user, pass);
    System.out.println(map2);
     String line;
     while((line = read.readLine()) !=null)
     {
        String[] split = line.split("\t\t");
        map.put(split[0], split[1]);

        if(map.equals(map2))
        {
            System.out.println("True");
        }
        else
        {
            System.out.println("False");
        }
     }
     System.out.println(map);
     read.close();
```

code for @SMA

```
     String line;
     while((line = read.readLine()) !=null)
     {
            String[] split = line.split("\t\t");
            map.put(split[0], split[1]);
            String passwordInFile = map.get(user);
             if (passwordInFile != null && passwordInFile.equals(pass)) 
                 System.out.println("True");
             else 
                 System.out.println("False");
     }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You shouldn't be comparing two maps. Instead compare for values in the map once you have all the values that are stored in a file like:

```
 String passwordInFile = map.get(user)
 if (passwordInFile != null && passwordInFile.equals(pass)) {
     System.out.println("True");
 } else {
     System.out.println("False");
 }
```

Comment: Thank you for reply. But it won't work... now I get false if I put same values as in my .txt file

Comment: @ClaudiuM Don't you think it would make sense to use the read `line` in your code somewhere? (I'm talking about your edited code snippet)

Comment: oh, you're right @Tom ! I forgot to paste that code sequence.

Comment: It seem to work now. But i still have a problem in while loop, for example, it prints false, false, true. If I use break in if and another break in else ofc, using { }, I get false for every condition, I think is because of last break from else which stops while loop

Comment: @SMA I finished my program. I'm beginner , I can understand what I did in my code, but, I need you to explain this code sequence please :)
 String passwordInFile = map.get(user)

Comment: It means using key as user i.e. what user has types in, i get password that i stored earlier while reading file.

Comment: I understood now. Thank you very very much sir !